# Invoke a custom method on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, methods, invoke

I want to invoke a custom method on a DOM element

like this :

```
<div id="MyObject">
    <!-- some elements -->
</div>

<script>
    function doSomething() {
        // do something with input DOM element
    }

    $("MyObject").doSomething();
</script>
```

How can I develop this problem? Is it necessary to use jQuery or not?

Comment: Is it bind to specific event like `click`, `hover` or etc? or you just want it to be a reachable value in the function?

Comment: no, I want to invoke every custom function on the input DOM element

Comment: Whats the reason to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need to use jQuery. You can use `document.getElementById('MyObject')` to get a reference to the DOM node.

To run your `doSomething` function on it, you would need to add a node parameter to it something like this:

```
function doSomething(input) {
  // do something with input DOM element
}

doSomething(document.getElementById('MyObject'));
```

To have it chained, you would need to add to the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) interface which all DOM nodes implement (rereading, I meant inherit from). If you go that way, you could do:

```
Element.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  alert(this);
}

document.getElementById('MyObject').doSomething();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lyb4b9p/

MDN: [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: I don't want to pass the name of DOM element to the functions, I want to invoke the function on every arbitrary DOM element.

Comment: @EmadArmoun Do you mean you want to define a function which is bound to every DOM element in generic ways?

Comment: I've never worked with prototype modifying before but I really wanted to make my element modifying function chain-able. I read a million different posts with not quite on the money answers until I finally found this super simple explanation of how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Without jQuery, you could do something like

```js
if (typeof $ != 'function') {
  //create a function $ which will return the element with said id
  window.$ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  }
}

//Add a method to the Elemen prototype so you can call it on any element object
Element.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  this.innerHTML = 'hi from inner';
}

$('MyObject').doSomething();
```

```html
<div id="MyObject">
  <!-- some elements -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by myself.

I can practice in this way :

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.doSomething = function () {
            // do something like this
            $(this).append("Hello Object");
        }
    } (jQuery));

    $("#MyDOMElement").doSomething();
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome solution, worked like a charm for me. I wanted to do it in jQuery